# JPQL, How to execute a query without a matched entity type?

Tags: group-by, entity, jpql, jsf-2.2

Say I get an entity from database, employee, and it has 3 attributes :

1.name(String)

2.id(String)

3.department(String).

Now I want to do a group-function query like: select e.department, count(e) from employee e group by e.department. I'm using EntityManager to create an executable query but question is no such entity fits the result, what should I do to do such a query and obtain the result?

Answer (score 0):

Your query will return results like this:

Department     Count
Dept1          10
Dept2          20

Assuming you have a [ResultSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) object:

```
while(rs.next()){
      String dept = rs.getString(1); //You can use column name if its defined
      int count = rs.getInt(2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.department, count(e) from employee e group by e.department
```

This jpql will give result as Object[] .

Then cast the result to required object.

```
for (Object[] o : resultList) {
    String department = (String) o[0];
    int e = (Integer) o[1];         
    System.out.println(department + " : " + e);
```

}

I think this will help you.